# .NET use IIF to assign value to different variables

Tags: .net, vb.net, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, iif

Could I (and if so how) do the following in .NET language (more specifically VB.NET):

```
Dim a,b as Integer
if(somecondition=1,a,b) = 12345
```

Or any variant with IIF would be fine by me.
Basically I'm always assign the same value but never to the same variable..

Comment: You can't use a construction like that. You could however have a single line statement like this: `If somecondition = 1 Then a = 12345 Else b = 12345`

Comment: I have, obvisouly, simplified my question (example) but it's more complicated and involves more than one conditions; plus my value is not as static as in my example.. Therefore I want to actualy avoid using multiple Ifs..

Comment: If your case is more complicated, it's hard to see how you hope to simplify it in this way. Perhaps you should edit your example to be a little more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking to do would have been possible in a language that supports pointer types (such as C/C++, or C# in unsafe mode) with dereferencing; VB.NET doesn't do that. The best you got to leverage is local variables, reference types, and (perhaps) `ByRef`.

If it's a `Class`, its instantiation is a reference type. `Structure` and `Integer` are each a value type.

For most reference types, you could just set a local variable equal to whichever variable was of interest, and then go ahead and set its properties or call its methods confident that the instantiation affected is the one desired. The one exception to this is when the reference is to an immutable type, such as `String`.

```
    Dim a, b As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = If(somecondition = 1, a, b)
    sb.Append("OK!")
```

Actually, one doesn't necessarily need a local variable with reference types.

```
    ' Method 2
    Call If(somecondition = 1, a, b).Append("OK!")

    ' Method 3
    With If(somecondition = 1, a, b)
        .Append("OK!")
    End With
```

For value types (and immutable classes), you're rather stuck. Mostly all one can do is make use of a local variable as a proxy, just as Jon Skeet has suggested.

A pattern I sometimes use myself:

```
    Dim a, b As Integer
    If True Then
        Dim _v As Integer = 12345
        If somecondition = 1 Then a = _v Else b = _v
    End If
```

Note the use of `If True Then` - this is so the lifetime of `_v` ends at the `End If`. The "so what" of that is to avoid either: (1) having a long list of temporary variables; or (2) taking the chance of common coding mistakes that involve the reuse of temporary variables. The temporary variable name (e.g. "_v") can then be reused, even as a different data type, because it will be a different variable to the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't believe there's any way of doing that in VB. Conditional operators (such as [`If(x, y, z)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985(v=vs.90).aspx)) are designed to evaluate one *expression* or the other based on a condition. In other words, it's the result that's conditional, not the use of it.

Just use a normal `If` statement:

```
If somecondition Then
    a = 12345
Else
    b = 12345
End If
```

Or to avoid repeating the value (e.g. if it's a more complicated expression):

```
Dim value As Integer = 12345
If somecondition Then
    a = value
Else
    b = value
End If
```

Comment: See my comment on original post

Comment: @jplanglais: That doesn't change the fact that you can't do it. You can avoid repeating the value using a local variable beforehand, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not in VB, but since assignment in C# returns the value assigned, you can do the following in C# (since you mentioned 'any .NET language'):

```
int unused = (someCondition ? a = 123 : b = 123);
```

Comment: Not really the same - OP is hoping for some kind of DRY pattern here. Maybe more like `*((someCondition==1)? &a : &b) = 12345`.